# Pass a list or other type to custom Ecto query

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a query like this one

```
select o.id::text, o.name, o.geom, o.tags, o.address, o.open
from organizations o, jsonb_array_elements(tags) as t
where t->>'text' in($1)
```

Is there any way I can pass a list (Array) to the query, I get an error if I pass a list this way `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(MyRepo, sql, ["tag1"])`

Comment: Does this work for you: `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(MyRepo, "... t->>'text' = ANY($1)", [["tag1", "tag2"]])`? (You also seem to have missed some lines in the SQL you posted.)

Comment: Not it doesn't work

Comment: Could you post the error you get with that code? I just checked that `ANY` should work just fine with jsonb like this if `t->>'text'` exists.

Comment: 1) test search radius 2 tags (Publit.SearchServiceTest)
     test/services/search_service_test.exs:47
     ** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: {:error, %Postgrex.Error{connection_id: 30238, message: nil, postgres: %{code: :syntax_error, file: "scan.l", line: "1081", message: "syntax error at or near \"any\"", pg_code: "42601", position: "218", routine: "scanner_yyerror", severity: "ERROR"}}}

Comment: also query and params
"select o.id::text, o.name, o.geom, o.tags, o.address, o.open\nfrom organizations o, jsonb_array_elements(tags) as t\nwhere o.open = true and ST_Distance_Sphere(o.geom, ST_MakePoint($1, $2)) <= $3 * 1000\n group by o.id"
[-18.1778, -63.8748, 2]
."select o.id::text, o.name, o.geom, o.tags, o.address, o.open\nfrom organizations o, jsonb_array_elements(tags) as t\nwhere o.open = true and ST_Distance_Sphere(o.geom, ST_MakePoint($1, $2)) <= $3 * 1000\n and t->>'text' any($4) group by o.id"
[-18.1778, -63.8748, 2, [["vegano", "vegetariano"]]]

Comment: You missed the `=` before `any`. Also you probably want to remove that extra array in the arguments: `[-18.1778, -63.8748, 2, ["vegano", "vegetariano"]]`.

Comment: Well I have done that in first place, but I have tried using `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(MyRepo, "... t->>'text' = ANY($1)", [["tag1", "tag2"]])` as you suggested in your first comment, it doesn't work even with just `["tag1", "tag2"]` and generates the same error

Comment: It works now my mistake was trying to use in but using any as you suggested works, I made a mistake not adding the `=` sign for any.